# Can Earth's Magnetic Field Be as Less as -85μT and as Much as +70.46μT?

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth, geophysics, geomagnetism

**What did create the question?**

I was analyzing a data set where the researchers have used objective data. They have calculated earth's magnetic field through sensors and that research was conducted in Bangladesh. I have read some articles ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field), [2](http://www.geophys.ac.cn/infowin/cc.asp), [3](https://www.crystalinks.com/earthsmagneticfield.html)) regarding earth's magnetic field and everywhere, I found that it ranges from 25 to 65 μT. However, in their data set, the different components (x, y, z axis) value of the magnetic field ranges from -85μT to +70.46μT. Even, there are many values which are less than 10μT.

**Therefore, my question**

Can different components (x, y, z axis) values of earth's magnetic field be as less as -85μT and as much as +70.46μT?

**So far, what I have found?**

[Here](https://web.ua.es/docivis/magnet/earths_magnetic_field2.html), I have found that

> The strength of the field at the Earth's surface ranges from less than
>   30 microteslas (0.3 gauss) in an area including most of South America
>   and South Africa to over 60 microteslas (0.6 gauss) around the
>   magnetic poles in northern Canada and south of Australia, and in part
>   of Siberia.

Moreover, [here](https://phys.org/news/2016-05-strength-earth-magnetic-field.html) I find

> It shows clearly that the field has weakened by about 3.5% at high
>   latitudes over North America, while it has strengthened about 2% over
>   Asia.

Furthermore, [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/answer-the-following-questionsa-the-earths-magnetic-field-varies-from/) in question a, I found that

> The earth's magnetic field varies from point to point in space.

**Then, what do I think?**

As the data set, I am working is regarding Bangladesh which is in south Asia, earth's magnetic field may vary from -85 to +70.46 μT. However, I am really confused as I do not find any literature or any reference where they have discussed that this value may vary so much. Moreover, I do not know, how and why this value of earth's magnetic field can deviate so much from the widely known 25μT to 65μT?

**Note:** I have checked some Q&A ([1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267158/how-strong-is-earths-magnetic-field-in-space), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62415/what-is-the-earths-magnetic-field-in-space), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111378/earths-magnetic-field), [4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41397/the-earths-magnetic-field)) of SE. But I did not find the answer. Moreover, I would like to mention that I do not have a good background of Physics.

---

**Update**

*Here is a little description of the data set:*

The earth magnetic field's data is presented in three different axis, that is, magnetic field value in x axis, y axis, z axis. They have retrieved these data for 30 minutes, on an interval of 1 sec. Therefore, there are many instances.

*What about the magnetic field of the city where the study was conducted?*

Setting the value of latitude, longitude (23.8103° N, 90.4125° E) and elevation 4m, I calculated the components (x, y, z) of the magnetic field using [this site](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml#igrfwmm).
I find that Y component value of magnetic field is negative and it is -0.2756μT which is near to 0. And these values seems to be similar of the data set, I am working.

[image: Table 1]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106378/discussion-on-question-by-md-sabbir-ahmed-can-earths-magnetic-field-be-as-less).